# Building a Red Black tree out of a sorted array

Tags: data-structures, search-trees

If I have a sorted array of size $n$, can I build a Red Black tree out of it in $O(n)$ time in a different algorithm rather than splitting the tree in half every time or the straightforward way that was mentioned in one of the answers?

Comment: @Trinarics And when the next answer comes along, will you again modify your question to ask for something else?

Comment: @FrankW no because that answer was what I have heard in class and I forgot to mention that I am looking for something different than it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done in a very straightforward way: Just build an almost complete tree and make the nodes on the lowest level red.